# Changing a value based on input from radio button

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, radio-button

I'm new to reactjs and was wondering what steps to take next. Basically, I want it so that when the radio button labelled as Social is clicked my mode field (in user schema) is changed to a value of 1 and when the radio button labelled as Professional is clicked, my mode field is changed to a value of 2. Any tips on where to get started. I've attached the bit of code with the radio buttons and my user schema. Right now I am planning on using onClick and then defining a function such that it updates the mode field in my user schema, so I guess my question is how to access and update a field from my user schema!

```
  <div class = "dropdown">
        <button class = "user-submit" id = "btn1">Current Profile Mode
          <i class = "fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <br></br>
        <div class = "dropdown-content">
          <input type="radio" id = "rd1" name="profile_type" value="Social" ></input>
          <label>Social</label><br></br>
          <input type="radio" id = "rd2" name="profile_type" value="Professional" ></input>
          <label>Professional</label><br></br>
        </div>
      </div> <br></br> 


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Link Schema
const LinkSchema = require('./Link').schema;

// Create User Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  userid: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  theme: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  mode: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
    default: 'uploads/default.png'
  },
  links: {
    type: [LinkSchema]
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Comment: if you don't mind changing ````value```` attr for ````buttons```` to **1** & **2** respectively rather holding their names, then you can retrieve their values using nodejs.

Comment: how about use state on onClick event radio

Comment: @agung_phe Yup, that's what I am aiming to do! I guess a better question would be how to access a field from the user schema and update it?